# IFs condition into Google script

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

im trying to convert this ifs into a script because the column F is dropped-down listing so i want the script to paste the result without hurting the data validation thing

what i really want is :
`
if E2='Not picked' then F2='Not Picked' and H2='no deduction'

if E2='Expired' then F2='Expired item' and H2='no deduction'

if E2='No Returned to branch' and F2='invalid proof' then H2='deduction'`

there is other 2 statements that similar to previous statements

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Can you please share a sample sheet with dummy data to replicate what you are trying to achieve and help us better visualize your goal?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iJ1ht-msJmhNpbNjHAkRcc7vWM-uittBeC89L01wrnw/edit?usp=sharing

here is the link of dummy data 

this selections represent what i need to do 

if E2='Not picked' then F2='Not Picked' and H2='no deduction'

if E2='Expired' then F2='Expired item' and H2='no deduction'

if E2='No Returned to branch' and F2='invalid proof' then H2='deduction'`
@SputnikDrunk2
@Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed your reply. And also, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer and discussion.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Suggestion

> ***NOTE**: This answer is intended to serve as a starting point or reference for your project. It's important to note that the community members do not provide coding services.*

To achieve the desired conditions and assign values to cells based on the contents of another cell, you can use a simple `OnEdit()` trigger, ***[Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)*** & JavaScript conditions in Google Apps Script.

Here's an example script that implements the conditions you described:

***[UPDATED]***

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var preserved_comment = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 7).getValue();

  if (col == 5) {
    e.value == 'Not picked' && e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 6, 1, 3).setValues([['Not Picked', preserved_comment, 'No deduction']])
    e.value == 'Expired' && e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 6, 1, 3).setValues([['Expired Items', preserved_comment, 'No deduction']]);
    e.value == 'Not returned to branch' && e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(`F${row}`).getValue() == 'Invalid proof' && e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 6, 1, 3).setValues([['Invalid proof', preserved_comment, 'Deduction']]);
  }

  if (col == 6) { //If E2 is equal to 'No Returned to branch' and F2 is equal to 'invalid proof', then set H2 to 'deduction'.

    e.value == 'Invalid proof' && e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(`E${row}`).getValue() == 'Not returned to branch' && e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 6, 1, 3).setValues([['Invalid proof', preserved_comment, 'Deduction']]);
  }
}
```

This Apps Script is an event-triggered function that responds to edits in column 5 of a Google Sheets document. Based on the value of the edited cell, it updates the adjacent cells in columns 6-8 with specific values, including the `preserved_comment` obtained from column 7 to keep the adjacent comments from being replaced/removed.

Here's the breakdown of what this script does:

1. If `E2` (presumably a variable or cell in a spreadsheet) is equal to '**Not picked**', then:

- *Set F2 to 'Not Picked'.*
- *Set H2 to 'no deduction'.*

2. If `E2` is equal to '**Expired**', then:

- *Set F2 to 'Expired item'.*
- *Set H2 to 'no deduction'.*

3. If `E2` is equal to '**No Returned to branch**' and `F2` is equal to '**invalid proof**', then:

- *Set H2 to 'deduction'.*

## Demo

[image]

## References

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Javascript Short Circuiting Operators](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-short-circuiting/)

Comment: i can't stop from thanking you for this great job and im really learning from that

once again maybe i had problem to clarify this 

third scenario that i need manual input ' not returned to branch' and ' invalid proof' both are manual inputs but the only automatic input will be ' deduction '

Comment: Clarification: When you mention *"manually input,"* are you referring to typing directly into the dropdown cell itself just like [this](https://imgur.com/a/IfMDeTs)?

Comment: i mean like manually selecting or typing, just having this two selection by user so i need only the script to choose deduction